# Do wizards regularly wear muggle clothing?

Tags: harry-potter

Arguments for: wizards have to enter a muggle railway station - so they cannot be wearing anything that can make muggles notice; the movies depict wizards wearing them at school all the time, except for ceremonies.

Argument against: a male wizard being chided for preferring female clothing since its less constricting as spectators in Quiddich world cup.

I was reading [Is there any muggle technology that is used in Harry Potter's world?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/64016/is-there-any-muggle-technology-that-is-used-in-harry-potters-world) and realized characters wearing muggle clothing in movies may not be a canonical. Check shirts and zippered jackets cannot be manufactured by magical industries.

Comment: I'm sure they just call it clothing.

Comment: Check out SciFi-SE. It has a quite similar question with good answers: [Do students wear muggle clothing while not in classes at Hogwarts](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144484/do-students-wear-muggle-clothing-while-not-in-classes-at-hogwarts-like-they-do)

Answer (score 1):

Your arguments for and against don't exclude each other, I feel they are complementary.
Wizards stick to their own world as much as possible, and mostly wear their own clothes. When/if they have to go about in the muggle world they sometimes "disguise" themselves as muggles, but this doesn't happen very often. You mention the railway station, but there are other means of transport as well, that don't require putting on muggle clothes. The man at the Quidditch world cup probably avoids the muggle world as much as possible.

Also when a witch or wizard has to do something on his or her own in the muggle world, they can just keep on their robes and raise an eyebrow or two on their way, but much more won't come of it. 
For larger events as the Quidditch world cup, where whole crowds of wizarding people have to gather, it might be customary or even required to put on muggle clothing to not draw attention to the high concentrations of wizards in one place.

The link to the SciFi-SE that @[Scorch91](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/37624/scorch91) commented ([Do students wear muggle clothing while not in classes at Hogwarts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144484/do-students-wear-muggle-clothing-while-not-in-classes-at-hogwarts-like-they-do)) also has some interesting and related views and information.

If you think about it, it is not just the clothes. The wizarding world in general is hesitant to adapt things from muggles. When Arthur Weasley created the flying car, it was considered abuse of magic and was frowned upon. 
They do, however, use a the Hogwarts Express, which is a train, created by muggles. 
They also adapted to use cameras for taking pictures, also a muggle invention. The cameras used were magically enhanced and then they stopped following the new muggle improvements (at least in the movies, who knows what kind of camera J.K. Rowling had in mind). 
In my eyes, the wizarding world finds it difficult to admit that muggles have a good idea every once in a while. 
The flying car was a hit and miss, but if Arthur Weasley fiddles around with some more muggle appliances, who knows, he might find the next proverbial camera.

Answer (score 1):

## They do.

As stated by J.K. Rowling on [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/clothing):

> The International Statute of Secrecy laid down clear guidelines on dress for witches and wizards when they are out in public.
>
> > When mingling with Muggles, wizards and witches will adopt an entirely Muggle standard of dress, which will conform as closely as possible to the fashion of the day. Clothing must be appropriate to the climate, the geographical region and the occasion. Nothing self-altering or adjusting is to be worn in front of Muggles.

More importantly however, looking at this quote from the same Pottermore article:

> Day to day, however, even those who detest Muggles wear a version of Muggle clothing, which is undeniably practical compared with robes. Anti-Muggles will often attempt to demonstrate their superiority by adopting a deliberately flamboyant, out-of-date or dandyish style in public.

We can imply that most wizards do regularly wear Muggle clothing. If even those who *detest* Muggles still wear Muggle or Muggle-like clothing simply out of convenience and/or practicality, then surely those who do not mind Muggles or are actively welcoming of them do the same.